Trying to convert html page to xml via nodejs
Im want to add sitemap route to my react website so I fetch the sitemap data and want to render a xml when user enter www.website.om/sitemap so I have this code in the backend:
const generateSitemap = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {

        const response = await fetch('https://www.mysitemapdata.app/sitemap.xml');
        const xmlData = await response.text();

        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.send(xmlData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching the sitemap:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching the sitemap');
    }
};

and I get this error in the backend terminal:
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\97254\Desktop\FeelThere\user-server-production\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:795:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\97254\Desktop\FeelThere\user-server-production\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:175:12)
    at generateSitemap (C:\Users\97254\Desktop\FeelThere\user-server-production\src\controllers\auth.controller.ts:114:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT
}

and this error in the browser console:
POST http://192.168.1.116/auth/sitemap net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
this is the frontend:
const FetchExternalXML = () => {
  const [xmlData, setXmlData] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSitemap = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("https://www.feelthere.app/sitemap.xml");
        const text = await res.text();
        setXmlData(text);
        await userService.sitemap(xmlData)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error while fetching sitemap:", err);
      }
    };

    fetchSitemap();
  }, []);

  return xmlData ? (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: xmlData }} />
  ) : (
    <p>Loading sitemap...</p>
  );
};

const sitemap = (data: any) => handlePostRequest(`auth/sitemap`, data)

My goal is to render this page as xml and not just html file
I tried the code above and its looks that its convert the header to xml but its doesn't
